# How do you use environment variables in the start up scripts in a passenger-docker container

Tags: docker, passenger

When I try to use an environment variable(`$HOME`) that I set in the Dockerfile, in the script that runs at start up, `$HOME` is not set.  If I run `printenv` in the container, $HOME is set.  So I am confused, and not sure what is going on.

I am using the phusion/passenger-customizable image, so that I can run a custom node server via pm2.  I need a different version of Node then what is bundled in the node specific passenger image.

### Dockerfile

```
# Simplified
FROM phusion/passenger-customizable:0.9.27
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"

# Set environment variables needed for the docker image.
ARG HOME=/opt/var/app
ENV HOME $HOME

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN mkdir /etc/service/app
ADD start.sh /etc/service/app/run
RUN chmod a+x /etc/service/app/run
```

### start.sh

```
echo $HOME
# run some scripts that reference the $HOME directory
```

What do I need to do to be able to reference a environment variable, set in the Dockerfile, in my start up scripts?  Or do I just need to hardcode the paths in that start up script and call it a day?

Comment: There is something else wrong with your setup. If you use `ENV` in the Dockerfile the variable will be available in the containers. Did you try to do `printenv` in your script? What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME` is reserved, in some fashion.  When running `printenv`, per @Sebastian, all my other variables where there but not `$HOME`. I prepended it with the initials of my company and it is working as intended.